# How can I deal with this "Error: list index out of range"?

Tags: python, youtube

Im beginner and I have a script that looking for videos on YouTube by search query with `youtube-search-python` package

How can I except this error `Error:  list index out of range`?

Code:

```
async def search(self, search: str):
        results = await asyncio.gather(*[self.to_search(search, page=i) for i in range(10)]) 
        count = sum([len(result['hits']) for result in results]) 
        print(f"Count of tracks from {search}: {count} ")
        return results 






from youtubesearchpython import VideosSearch


class YoutubeSample:
    def get_link(self, *args):
        try:
            producer_name, search = args[0]
            videos_search = VideosSearch(producer_name + search, limit=1).result()

            print("Youtube link for: ", producer_name, search, "Name of video: ", videos_search['result'][0]['title'])
            return videos_search
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error: ", e)
            return None
```

Output:

```
Youtube link for:  PewDiePie
Error:  list index out of range
Youtube link for:  Mr Beat 
Error:  list index out of range
```

Comment: `list index out of range` when you call `list[0]` could mean that the list is empty.

Comment: How do you call `get_link()` ?
Provide code for the call please.
Needed to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @MasterMind you should give you whole code, so your problem can be solved.

Comment: @TrooperZ yes but how can I "skip" of catching empty list?

Answer (score 1):

If the list is empty, you can check that by checking the length of the list of results through something like this:

```
if videos_search['result'].length == 0:
   print("No results found")
else:
   # run the code
```

Comment: O! That's look useful!

and I just tried to add it but still when im run the code it return me same error.